# Using Two Views and switch between Views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, user-controls

I see example on this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views), how to switch between two views. Easiest sollution and perfect for my application - I will also have only two views.

So we have one parent View (MainWindow) and two children Views. Parent View have dedicadet two buttons to swtich between this two Views ("First View" and "Second View") which are located in "DockPanel".

My question is how to use any button in "First View" to switch to the second View and in "Second View" button to come back to the "First View". What I want is get rid of DockPanel and use buttons from View.

Please for advices, how to do that. If any question please ask. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an event from each child viewmodel to signal the parent to change views. So in the code below ButtonOnViewModel1Command is pressed on View1 (which is bound to ViewModel1) which raises the SwitchViewModel2Request event.  The MainViewModel subscribes to this event and switches the CurrentViewModel collection to ViewModel2.  You can do this same thing on ViewModel2 to switch back to ViewModel1.

```
 public class MainViewModel
{
    private ViewModel1 _viewModel1 = new ViewModel1();
    private ViewModel2 _viewModel2 = new ViewModel2();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //event from ViewModel1 
        _viewModel1.SwitchViewModel2Request += NavigateToView2;
    }

    //switch View to ViewModel2
    private void NavigateToView2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentViewModel = _viewModel2;
    }
}
public class ViewModel1
{
    public ViewModel1()
    {
        ButtonOnViewModel1Command = new RelayCommand(Button1Method);
    }  
    //some button on child view 1
    public RelayCommand ButtonOnViewModel1Command { get; set; }


    private void Button1Method(object obj)
    {
        OnSwitchViewModel2Request();
    }

    //event that MainViewModel will subscribe to
    public event EventHandler SwitchViewModel2Request = delegate { };
    private void OnSwitchViewModel2Request()
    {
        SwitchViewModel2Request(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using MVVM light you should look to using the messenger system ( [Good tutorial here](http://wpfapptutorial.com/mvvm-light-messenger) ).  A simple way would be on first view to send a NotificationMessage as follows:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage("GotoSecondView"));
```

Then in your main window you would register to receive it as follows:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotificationReceived);
```

Followed by a function to handle them:

```
    private void NotificationReceived(NotificationMessage message)
    {
        string notice = message.Notification;

        switch (notice)
        {
            case "GotoSecondView":
                ExecuteSecondViewCommand
                break;
        }
    }
```

Repeat the same idea for the other view and add it to your switch.  Then you can trigger from anywhere and mainview will handle the change without directly having to link your viewmodels.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that only difference from link example is: I will be not use MVVM Light. SORRY! Thanks for link, I overview anyway, maybe sollution is there. Thanks!

Comment: Idealy you want to use something like I posted.  If you're wanting to go dirt simple and not ideal then just pass the main window instance to the first and second view when it creates them and have a function on it they can call to change views.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.